# Конкатенация элементов двух списков в один (по индексу)

Tags: python, list, список

Есть два списка одинаковой длины:

```
l1 = ["Hello", "Arcady", "My"]
l2 = ["World", "Petrovich", "Name"]
```

Необходимо получить один список, который бы соединял элемент каждого списка, например:

```
l3 = ["Hello World", "Arcady Petrovich", "My Name"]
```

Пытаюсь сделать через цикл, но он не правильно работает

```
def Concat(l1, l2):
    l3 = []
    for t1 in l1:
        for t2 in l2:
            if t2!="":
                l3.append(t1 + " + " + t2)
            else:
                l3.append(t1)
    return l3
```

Comment: `list(map(' '.join, zip(l1, l2)))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
l1 = ["Hello", "Arcady", "My"]
l2 = ["World", "Petrovich", "Name"]
l3 = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(l1, l2)]
print(l3)  # ['Hello World', 'Arcady Petrovich', 'My Name']
```

---

Алгоритм:

- `zip` составит список пар:

> ```
> list(zip(l1, l2))  # [('Hello', 'World'), ('Arcady', 'Petrovich'), ('My', 
> 'Name')]
> ```

- В цикле будут перебираться пары и через `join` объединены:

> ```
> ' '.join(('Hello', 'World'))  # 'Hello World'
> ```

Если без функции, то:

`l3 = [x[0] + ' ' + x[1] for x in zip(l1, l2)]`

или:

`l3 = [a + ' ' + b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]`

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите оставить просто цикл, то вот решение:

```
res = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    res.append(l1[i] + " " + l2[i])
```

или

```
res = [l1[i] + " " + l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))]
```